# Find the number of rooms availble from the below table structure

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the following table structure:

- `roominfo` table

  ```
  +---------+----------------+---------------+
  | Room_id | room_type_name | maximum_rooms |
  +---------+----------------+---------------+
  |       1 | A              |            16 |
  |       2 | B              |            14 |
  |       3 | C              |             7 |
  |       4 | D              |             2 |
  |       5 | E              |             2 |
  +---------+----------------+---------------+
  ```
- `bookedtable` stores all the rooms booked within that date:

  ```
  +------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
  | room_bk_id | checkin_date | checkout_date | maxroomsbooked | room_id |
  +------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
  |          1 | 2014-01-28   | 2014-01-29    |              8 |       1 |
  |          2 | 2014-01-29   | 2014-01-30    |              2 |       4 |
  |          3 | 2014-01-28   | 2014-01-29    |              4 |       1 |
  +------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
  ```
- `bookingprogress` table to avoid the race condition (it blocks upto the expire time) I set the maximum expire time as 15 minutes from current time

  ```
  +------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
  | room_pg_id | checkinpg_date | checkoutpg_date | maxroomsbooked | room_id |   sessionid   |     ExpireTime      |
  +------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
  |          1 | 2014-01-28     | 2014-01-29      |              2 |       1 | AdsddsA23asd  | 2014-01-28 00:15:00 |
  |          2 | 2014-01-29     | 2014-01-30      |              2 |       5 | AdsQWerasdwe  | 2014-01-28 00:18:00 |
  |          3 | 2014-01-28     | 2014-01-29      |              1 |       2 | BdrtQWerasdwe | 2014-01-28 00:20:00 |
  +------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
  ```

The workflow is:

1. User checks for the available rooms by providing checkin date, checkout date and no of rooms.
2. I need to find and display the rooms are available which are not blocked or booked for that particular period.

**The executed query was  (might be small mistakes -- Here I gave overview of what I have done --So modified my query according to that)**

```sql
SELECT   tbook.*,
         SUM(tbook.maxroomsbooked + tprogress.maxroomsbooked) AS bookedrooms
FROM     bookedtable     AS tbook
    JOIN bookingprogress AS tprogress USING (Room_id)
    JOIN roominfo        AS troomtype USING (Room_id)
WHERE    tbook.checkout_date       > '2014-01-28'
     AND tprogress.checkoutpg_date > '2014-01-28'
     AND tprogress.ExpireTime      < '2014-01-27 00:10:00'
     AND tprogress.room_id         = 1
GROUP BY Room_id
```

From the above tables I tried to get the rooms which are available for booking. But I didn't get the expected result.

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b31f/1/0).

Could you please provide me with the solution?

Comment: can you add what you have tried?

Comment: add your code here, which can give us a better idea of your situation.

Comment: Your date literals are in the format dd-mm-yyyy, which is not a valid format in MySQL... is that just a typographical error, or are you actually storing dates as strings in that format?

Comment: @eggyal thats a sample. Actually it stored in YYYY-dd-mm format. There is no syntax error on this.

Comment: Okay.  I *think* I've fixed your sample so that it now makes sense - by all means correct it if I'm wrong.  Before looking any further, one immediate comment is that you probably want to work with a union of `bookedtable` and `bookingprogress` rather than a join between them...

Comment: @eggyal Thanks you very much.I dont know how to thanks you.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that someone clever enough to think of having a 'race condition' table can't figure out how to use it! :-)

Comment: @Strawberry :) Its not a surprise...everyone learning on everyday ...learned one day about the race condition..now trying to find the solution to avoid it..

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [`NOT EXISTS` subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).  For example, if a user is interested in booking `'2014-02-01'` to `'2014-02-07'`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   roominfo r
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   bookedtable b
         WHERE  b.room_id = r.room_id
            AND NOT (
                  b.checkin_date  < '2014-02-07'
              AND b.checkout_date > '2014-02-01'
                )
         LIMIT  1
       )
   AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   bookingprogress p
         WHERE  p.room_id = r.room_id
            AND p.ExpireTime > CURRENT_TIME
            AND NOT (
                  p.checkinpg_date  < '2014-02-07'
              AND p.checkoutpg_date > '2014-02-01'
                )
         LIMIT  1
       )
```

Comment: I have a doubt whether it will return the row for the rooms having entry in progress as well as booked (Example A having both entry , but still the room is available for booking ) , whether it will return that row